# React Refuses to render a div

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a web application and my application works for the most part except I cannot see the /tasks section. I do not understand because it is the same as the rest of my elements.

```js
import React, {
  Component,
  Fragment
} from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom';

import AppProvider, {
  Consumer
} from './AppProvider';
import Login from './Login';
import Signup from './Signup';

import Navbar from './Navbar';
import FlashMessage from './FlashMessage';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppProvider>
        <Router>
          <Fragment>
            <Navbar />
            <FlashMessage />
            <Route exact path="/" component={() =>
              <h1 className="content">Welcome, Home!</h1>} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={() => <Login />} />
            <Route exact path="/signup" component={() => <Signup />} />
            <Router exact path="/tasks" component={() =>
              <h1 className="content">Content Should Go Here</h1>} />
            <Route exact path="/signedOut" component={() =>
              <h1 className="content">You're now signed out.</h1>} />
            <Route exact path="/accountCreated" component={() =>
              <h1 className="content">Account created. <Link
to="/login">
              Proceed to Dashboard</Link></h1>} />
          </Fragment>
        </Router>
      </AppProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The content div routed at /tasks won't display anything. There are no errors, I have checked in the console. All I want is it to display the content on /tasks.

Comment: looks like you're not rendering the Tasks component though. You just have the h1 for that route.

Comment: I am rendering the entire App class in another index.js file. All I want is /tasks to render the div inside the component= section.

Comment: You want to use `Route` or `Router` with `/tasks`? I think you need `Route`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is you are using the `BrowserRouter` in your "./tasks" instead of use `route`.

Comment: Thank you so so much I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you have a trailing Slash on your link.

Comment: This is the code below so Yes I do have a slash at the end
<Router exact path="/tasks" component={() => 
<h1 className="content">Content Should Go Here</h1>} />